# Proving the limit of $f(x)$ is infinity for any continuous function with these conditions

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have to prove that:  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$ for any continuous $f(x)$ such that: $f(0)=1$ and $\forall x: f(x)\ne x$.

The supplied solution for the question uses
$h(x)=f(x)-x\ne0$
such that $h(0)=1$
however I fail to understand how this helps prove that $h(x)>0$ let alone that $f(x)>x$ (which is enough for QED).

If someone can think of a proof along those lines or explain the one above, that would be appreciated, however, any solution would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there exists $x>0$ such that $h(x)<0$. Since $h(0)=1>0$ you can use the intermediate value theorem to get a contradiction, which yields $h(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can take a look at the elaboration i added and tell me if it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Thank You to Mundron Schmidt for the answer, just thought I'd spell it out for those who are in the same position as me.

To prove $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$ we need to prove $\forall x:f(x)>x$. Since we know that $f(x)\ne x$, we only need to **disprove** that $\exists x:f(x)<x$:

Let function $h(x)$ be defined as:
$h(x)=f(x)-x$ and since $f(x)\ne x$, we get $h(x)\ne 0$. If we can **disprove** that $\exists x:h(x)<0$, we can say that $\forall x:f(x)-x>0\Rightarrow\forall x:f(x)>x$:

According to the  [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem):
for any two points $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ in a continuous function, there exists a point $f(c)$ such that $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$
($\forall a,b\exists c|f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$)

Therefore, for $\exists a:h(a)<0$, we would need  $\exists c:h(c)=0$ if $h(b)=h(0)=1$. However, we already proved that $h(x)\ne 0$, and therefore $\exists a:h(a)<0$ cannot be true $\blacksquare$

Comment: You have to be more careful with your equations, i.e. the negation of $\forall x:f(x)>x$ is $\exists x:f(x)\leq x$.<p>

Comment: It would be, however we also have that $f(x)\ne x$

Comment: Your last part and Intermediate value theorem is mixed and confusing. It would be better to write: "Assume there exists $a>0$ such that $h(a)<0$. Since $h(0)=1>0$ the Intermediate value theorem yields a point $y\in(0,a)$ such that $h(y)=0$ which contradicts $h(x)\neq 0$ for all $x>0$. Therefore the assumption is wrong and wir get $h(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. This implies $f(x)>x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $h(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ we can deduce that its sign remains constant. If that were not the case then we would have a $x_1,x_2$ such that $h(x_1)>0,h(x_2)<0$ and from Bolzano's Theorem i.e. Intermediate Value theorem there would exist a root. Now observe the value of $h(0)=1-0>0$. Thus $h(x)$ is always positive, ergo $f(x)>x$. Taking limits on both sides yields the claim.

Just thought I'd post a more concise version of the proof.